# Processing raw binary data with Racket

Tags: racket

I am new to Racket Lang and previously I wrote thousands of lines of code in C++, Java and C. I am trying to figure out how to do the following task:

- Given an array (like C uint8_t array) with the following format:

  - First byte is used to indicate the "format", let's say this could be 0x0a, 0x0b and so on.
  - Remaining data may include C strings without the null terminator and integers.
- Write a function that parses the array and puts the values in some variables.

Before asking here, I was reading: https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide and also https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference

My approach is as follows:

- I am using a byte string because it seems it can be used to mimic the C++/C arrays.
- I am using tail recursion to traverse the "array".

Questions:

1) In C, I always use the return value of a function as an error code: 0 is ok and any negative value is an error. With Racket, I am using multiple return values to indicate: a) the return code, b) the processed value(s), i.e. something like:

(values return_code out1 out2 ...)

What do you think? Do you recommend the use of exceptions for error handling?

2) What's the best approach to process arrays in Racket? I mean, the best according to the offered by Racket and to achieve a good performance.

Thanks!

**Edit1:**
Regarding my first question (the return codes), I am calling many functions and I would like to return an exit code that helps me to know if there was an error inside the function. This is a sample code:

```
#lang racket

(define (is_valid in)
  (cond
    [(and (>= in 10) (<= in 15)) #t]
    [else #f]))

(define (copy_values in)
  (define len (bytes-ref in 2))
  ; 3 is where the string "ABCD" begins
  (define str (subbytes in 3 (+ 3 len)))
  (define numbers (subbytes in (+ 3 len)))
  (values str numbers))

(define (parse in)
  (define type (bytes-ref in 0))
  (if (is_valid type)
      (let ()
        (define-values (str numbers) (copy_values in))
        (values #t str numbers))
      (values #f 0 0)))

; format:           type  strlen
;                       len   |-- str --| | -- numbers -- |
;                          
(define input1 (bytes 10 10 4 65 66 67 68 110 120 130 140 150))

(define input2 (bytes 1 10 4 65 66 67 68 110 120 130 140 150))

(parse input1)
(parse input2)
```

This is the output in DrRacket:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.7 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
#t
#"ABCD"
#"nx\202\214\226"
#f
0
0
```

Look how I use the (values ...) stuff, does that make sense?

Comment: What is a C string without a null terminator?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @benrudgers a C string is something like "abc\0" where '\0' is the null character. The input I am parsing is something like: 0x0a 3 'a' 'b' 'c'. Regarding the code I've tried: just a function that traverses the array and stores the de-codified values into another array. Sorry for not posting here the code, it is still a mess..

Answer (score 0):

To return a value to the operating system, use [(exit *[v]*).](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Exiting.html?q=exit#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._exit%29%29). Other values should probably go to standard out and/or standard error. This means writing them before the program exits.

In terms of assigning the values of an array to variables, there are many ways to do it depending on how lexical scope comes into play within the function and module and across modules. Also reference semantics versus value semantics are considerations.

Finally, there is no compelling reason to choose recursion over an explicit loop when dealing with a `byte-string`. `bytes-length` is a low level primitive implemented in C and will return the length needed for a loop without testing for an empty byte-string.

Comment: Except that loops in Scheme systems are just syntactic sugar for recursion so you just add an abstraction.

Comment: @Sylwester The abstractions described in the question center around C arrays. Recursion + arrays will work, but it is a dubious combination of abstractions. Anyway, without a tip of the hat to iteration, there is no reason at all to use tail recursion over non-tail recursion...and the turtle at the bottom of the Von Neumann architecture is iteration and recursion is always syntactic sugar when push comes to shove.

Comment: @benrudgers no! there is no turtle at the bottom! It's turtles all the way down! La la la la la, I don't hear you.... :)